# Show that Function is Path Dependent

Tags: integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Hi there here is a question that I have wrecking my head for quite sometime I hope that the experts could assist me!

Show that *I* = $\int_c (x^2y dx + 2xy^2 dy)$ is path dependent in the xy-plane.

I know that I have to use the Test for Analyticity by the Cauchy Riemann Equation where Ux = Vy and Uy = -Vx.

However that method only works via a complex function which I am confused as the above question cannot be converted into a complex function ie. z = x = iy.

Please assist. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the path independence on a simply closed region, one only has to show that the curl is equal to the zero vector.

Here: $\vec{F}=(x^2y,2xy^2,0)^T$, with curl$(\vec{F})=(0,0,2y^2-2xy)^T$. Clearly this vector is not equal to zero. Hence, the integral is pathdependent.

Comment: Thank you! It really helped!